# Simple UPDATE SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a work for a client but since I haven't been using PHP/MySQL for a while I forgot some simple things, hope you can help me out.

I have the following SQL table:

```
ID (non-null, autoincrement) | credit (int)
```

My query should put the whole "credit" column to 0 except for the row that has the higher ID.

So I would do:

```
UPDATE $table SET credit = 0 WHERE... ?
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE $table SET credit = 0 WHERE ID > $ID
```

Will update any rows that have and ID greater than the variable `$ID`

If you only want to update the row with the maximum ID then use:

```
UPDATE $table SET credit = 0 WHERE ID = (select max(id) from $table)
```

Edit: As Eggyal correctly points out MySQL doesn't like a subquery on the same table as an update - but you can get around it nicely:

```
UPDATE $table 
    SET credit = 0 
    WHERE 
        credit='$credit' 
        AND statid='$statid' 
        AND userid='$userid' 
        AND ID = (select ID from (SELECT MAX(ID)as ID from $table) a)
```

And examples from my console:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | eeee  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update first set title='ffff' where id=(select max(id) from first);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'first' for update in FROM clause

mysql> update first set title='ffff' where id=(select ID from (select max(id) as ID from first) a);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | ffff  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: As the subquery within a subquery trick unlocks the original table, it is a good idea to run this within a transaction - if the table is unlocked from a query, it might have changed by the time it is updated - so it will be a good idea to use this type of query within a transaction.

Comment: It looked to be working, but I get: You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause!

Comment: @MarcelloSilvestri You shouldn't have a `from` clause in an update statement. What is your entire SQL?

Comment: UPDATE $table SET credit = 0 WHERE credit='$credit' AND statid='$statid' AND userid='$userid' AND ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) from $table)

(credit, statid and userid must be equal to the one inserted in a previous form)

Comment: [Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html)

Comment: Nothing to do Fluffeh, I get: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @MarcelloSilvestri Yeah, I forgot to alias it, but have already updated it with working example as well.

Comment: @eggyal There is a simple workaround for it though which I included in my answer now. Use a subquery on a subquery. Works a charm.

Comment: @Fluffeh, can you help me understand why this works yet referencing the table from a direct subquery does not?  Surely the locking issues that gave rise to that restriction still exist in this case, or else there is a concurrency risk (that a new record is inserted between the `MAX` being evaluated and the `UPDATE` being performed)?

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for all the support!

Comment: @eggyal I recall reading ages ago that it was the way that mysql treats a lock on a table in a direct subquery, but when it is nested in another subquery, it somehow releases the lock and can use the data in the outer query. To be honest, when I got it working the first time, I was so happy I didn't read all the details, just never forgot the trick :) (it's a *GEM* though right?)

Comment: @Fluffeh: aye, I suspected it might be that... but in that case, the concurrency risk is quite severe.  I'd *strongly* suggest this query be executed within a transaction (if using InnoDB: but will that be sufficient?) or else that a manual lock is taken on the table (if using MyISAM) -- perhaps worth including a warning to that effect in your answer?